# Where can I get AA or AAX file format?

Tags: mac, iphone, mp3, file-extension, aac

I need to test a *AA* and *AAX* file format for iphone testing. 
I tried google searching with filetype:aax. But I could't find it easily.
Where do I find these samples?

Comment: Considering it's a heavily DRM'd file type developed specifically for selling audiobooks, the chance of finding any available for free is fairly slim. You could always sign up to the audible site and buy some...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find samples on [The FreeSound Project](http://www.freesound.org/) (free registration is required to download).

For example, one AAX sample is found [here](http://www.freesound.org/samplesViewSingle.php?id=61525) and an AA sample [here](http://www.freesound.org/samplesViewSingle.php?id=49077), but many more are available.